# Selenium 2 with Python bindings will not install correctly

Tags: selenium, python-2.7

I have installed Selenium 2 with Python on multiple machines but on one machine(Windows 7 64bit) I can not get it to install. I installed Pip or so I think. It exists in my scripts folder. I have made the enviorment variable path ;C:\Python27\Scripts per the instructions. I tryed to install the pip setup tool but it says it can not find Python in the registry. I believe I installed Python(I know I installed Pythion just not sure if its 32 or 64 and am not sure how to check.) for 64 bit was this a wrong move. When I install Selenium via pip install selenium I get an Importerror no entry load package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i faced the same problem try to download the setuptools from that link
 (setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe)
http://htpcbuild.com/htpc-software/python-setup-tools/python-setup-tools-install-guide/ 
and put the variable path ;c:\python27 .it worked for me that way